# How to pass xml data between c# and java sockets

Tags: c#, java, xml, sockets

I have a c# server and a java client. Currently they pass plain text between each other using sockets. Now I want to change these sockets to communicate in XML. I can implement the java side, But i do not know how to implement the c# server side so that the server and the client could communicate without any problem.
Are there any special technologies/libraries that I could use for this? at least a pointer to some examples is appreciated.

thanks

/Suralk

Comment: hey sorry. i ddnt know that we could vote for the answers.

Comment: No I don't mean voting for answers. Click the empty check mark next to the answer to accept it. That means you feel it is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Use XmlDocument to create XML. Then you can send the complete string of that XML (xmlDoc.OuterXml) using TcpClient. Then using TcpClient you can also wait for the response.

Comment: what about the c# side? is there any special mechanism for XML? I could not find any

Comment: XmlDocument is C#. None of what I was referring to is java.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a web service (WCF in C#). Both Java and C# can read a WSDL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

http://teaching.cs.uml.edu/~heines/tools/JRun4/docs/html/Programmers_Guide/ws_wsdl5.html

Comment: web services would be bit too much for my application. both client and server are running in the server machine. I use sockets because that is the easiest way to communicate between c# and java applications residing in the same machine