# How to Communicate on network using XML?

Tags: c#, xml, communication

I am developing a LAN messenger in c# using sockets, i want to use XML for entire communication, can you people help me? or give me some link or code snippet?
any help will be appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some more details? What kind of messages will your application be sending?

Comment: why not use WCF? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690929(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @ keith  the messages will be normal "Chatting"(string messages), i want these messages to be verified by DTD

Comment: @ Caspar Kleijne, personally i want to use WCF, but the requirement(given to me) was like that.
 

 
You're required to implement a LAN Messenger software.

Feature List 
 -  Chat with One or Multiple Friends at a time.
 -  Notification Icon of application in System Tray. 
 -  Popup window when a friend signs in.
Note  
 -  Entire communication shall be done using XML.
 -  Each message will be verified using DTD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see discussion @:

- [Sending XML data via socket](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32775477/sending-xml-data-via-socket.aspx)
- [How to pass xml data between c# and
  java sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315786/how-to-pass-xml-data-between-c-and-java-sockets)